# Getting error code, but don't know why

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I need to write a code for a fraction calculator that can add, subtract, multiply, and divide two fractions.  I have this code and am getting the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at Calculator.run(Calculator.java:24)
    at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:13)
```

I know the error message gives me the spot I need to fix but I cannot figure out what i have done wrong.  I am still pretty new to Java so it is probably a very easy fix.

Thank you in advance.

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter two fractions to add, subtract, multiply, or divide\nor\nType 'quit' to exit the program.");
        Boolean on = true;
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (on) {
            String input = console.nextLine();
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                on = false;
            } else
                System.out.println(run(input));
        }
    }

    public static String run(String input) {
        int indexOfSecondSpace = 0;
        int indexOfOperation = 0;
        String firstNumber = "0";
        String secondNumber = "0";
        int beginning = input.indexOf(" ") + 1;
        int end = input.indexOf(" ", input.indexOf(" "));
        String operator = input.substring(beginning, end);
        if (input.contains("+") == true) {
            indexOfOperation = input.indexOf("+");
        } else if (operator.equals("-")) {
            indexOfOperation = input.indexOf("-");
        } else if (operator.equals("*")) {
            indexOfOperation = input.indexOf("*");
        } else if (operator.equals("/")) {
            indexOfOperation = input.indexOf("/");
        }
        firstNumber = (input.substring(input.indexOf(" ")));
        secondNumber = (input.substring(input.indexOf(" ") + 1));
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int d = 0;  
        if (firstNumber.contains("/")) {
            a = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.substring(0,firstNumber.indexOf("/")));
            b = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.substring(0),firstNumber.indexOf("/"));
        } else if (!firstNumber.contains("/"))
            a = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, input.indexOf(" ")));
            b = Integer.parseInt("1");
        {
            if (secondNumber.contains("/")) {
                c = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.substring(secondNumber.indexOf("/")));
                d = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.substring(secondNumber.indexOf("/" + 1, secondNumber.length())));
            } else if (!secondNumber.contains("/")) {
                c = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.substring(secondNumber.length()));
                d = Integer.parseInt("1");
            }
        }
        return input;

    }
    public static String calculate(String input, int a, int b, int c, int d){
    if (input.contains ("+"))
    {
        System.out.println("your answer is " + (a*d + b*c)+"/" +(b*d));
    }
    else if  (input.contains("-"))
    {
        System.out.println("your answer is " + (a*d - b*c)+ "/" +(b*d));
    }
    else if (input.contains("/"))
    {
        System.out.println("your answer is " + (a*d)/(b*c)+ "/" +(b*d));
    }
    else if (input.contains("*"))
    {
        System.out.println("your answer is " + (a*c) +"/" +(b*d));
    }
    return input;
}
}
```

Comment: The message is telling you that you have a string index out of bounds on line 24. Does your Integrated Development Environment show you which line is line 24? When you have the lines like input.indexOf(" "), you might not be finding any spaces. This would make the indexOf return a -1.

Answer (score 2):

The `String.indexOf` method will return -1 if the string was not found. At this snipplet you have:

```
int beginning = input.indexOf(" ") + 1;
int end = input.indexOf(" ", input.indexOf(" "));
```

Resulting in

```
int beginning = input.indexOf(" ") + 1; // = -1 + 1 = 0
int end = input.indexOf(" ", input.indexOf(" ")); // input.indexOf(" ", -1); ERROR!
```

And you likely ment is:

```
int beginning = input.indexOf(" ") + 1; // = -1 + 1 = 0
int end = input.indexOf(" ", beginning ); // input.indexOf(" ", 0); Great job!
```

Answer (score 0):

ug_'s answer is right.. by the way, your method run() contains plenty of errors (i tried to run it)

i thought a fixed version would be useful to you.. here it is: ( check the substring() methods ;) )

```
public static String run(String input) {
int indexOfSecondSpace = 0;
int indexOfOperation = 0;
String firstNumber = "0";
String secondNumber = "0";
int beginning = input.indexOf(" ") + 1;
int end = input.indexOf(" ", beginning);
String operator = input.substring(beginning, end);
if (input.contains("+") == true) {
    indexOfOperation = input.indexOf("+");
} else if (operator.equals("-")) {
    indexOfOperation = input.indexOf("-");
} else if (operator.equals("*")) {
    indexOfOperation = input.indexOf("*");
} else if (operator.equals("/")) {
    indexOfOperation = input.indexOf("/");
}
firstNumber = (input.substring(0, input.indexOf(" ")));
secondNumber = (input.substring(beginning + 1));
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int d = 0;  
if (firstNumber.contains("/")) {
    a = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.substring(0,firstNumber.indexOf("/")));
    b = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.substring(0,firstNumber.indexOf("/")));
} else if (!firstNumber.contains("/"))
    a = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, input.indexOf(" ")));
    b = Integer.parseInt("1");
{
    if (secondNumber.contains("/")) {
        c = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.substring(secondNumber.indexOf("/")+1));
        d = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.substring(secondNumber.indexOf("/")+1));
    } else if (!secondNumber.contains("/")) {
        c = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.substring(secondNumber.length()));
        d = Integer.parseInt("1");
    }
}
return input;
}
```

Comment: so now i know this is a stupid question but for some reason it is returning what was put in and not doing any calculations. i know it has something to do with return input; but i dont know how to change it to return an answer. i used the debugger and found out that the second method of my program is not even being executed. Again i am new to java. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: @diy900 well, before `return input;` in your `run() ` method you should call your `calculate()` method. You can achieve this sobstituting `return input` with this: `String res = calculate(input, a, b, c, d) ; return res;`

Comment: This help is very much apreciated.  The problem I had was solved. I knew it was something simple its just being new to java I didn't exactly know hoe to fix it.